# AngularJS ui-router : i have send param to $state.go() to nested state and nothing happened

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state like this

```
.state('topic.content', {
    url: '/:id',
    resolve: {
        topicContent: ($stateParams, TopicService) => {
            return TopicService.getContent({ topicId: $stateParams.id }).$promise
        }
    },
    controller: 'topicCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/topic.html',
})
```

I'm trying to go to this state with this code

```
$state.go('topic.content', { 'id': res.id })
```

res.id is "58ba84164e1af51e2c19aa1d" and 24 characters length.

But there is nothing happened and no error in my console. Next I tried all of the below

```
$state.go('topic.content', {id:'58ba84164e1af51e2c19aa1d'})

// or

let params = { id: '58ba84164e1af51e2c19aa1d' }
$state.go('topic.content', params)
```

All of them made no difference. But with the below

```
$state.go('topic.content', {id:'1234567890'})

// or

$state.go('topic.content', {id:'123456789012345678901234'}) // 24 length :)

// or

$state.go('topic.content', {id:'abcd567890abcd5678901234'})
```

All of this was success and can be change to topic.content state.

So, What am I doing wrong? And thank you so much from the beginner.

PS: if you are clear what I meant, sorry for my English.

Comment: Does `TopicService.getContent` take only hexadecimal values by any chance?

Comment: Yes sir. it take only id of topic (hexadecimal). Thank you.

Comment: your problem is probably within the resolve callback, since you have no errors and nothing happens. try to debug to see what is the value of `id` in resolver, and make sure, your service is actually reaching your REST.